# Sequelize association error `something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I encountered the following error while creating associations in Sequelize:

```
${source.name}.${_.lowerFirst(Type.name)} called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Error: User.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

I updated both `Node.js` and `Sequelize` to the latest versions. But it didn't help.
I used the `Sequelize CLI` to recreate the exact association in a new project, but the error still exists

I would appreciate any suggestions in advance

Comment: Please show model definitions, associations and where and how you register all of them